# SAS: Why is the string trimmed at position 955

Tags: sas

I'm trying to concatenate retained values.
This is my piece of code:

```
data &_output.;
set &_input.;
by cpn;
retain json_array;
if first.cpn and last.cpn then do;
   flag = 'both';
   concat = ('subscriptions:[{'||'"mpc" : "'||compress(mpc)||'" ,    '||'"contract_start_date" : "'||compress(contract_start_date)||'" '||' , "contract_end_date" : "'||compress(contract_end_date)||'"'||' , "subscription_status_code" : "'||compress(subscription_status_code)||'"'||' , '||'"promo_code" : "'||compress(promo_code)||'" '||' , "print_or_digi_flag" : "'||compress(print_or_digi_flag)||'"'||' , "payment_method_selection" : "'||compress(payment_method_selection)||'"'||', "subscription_type_code" : "'||compress(subscription_type_code)||'"'||' , "report_trial_subscription" : "'||compress(report_trial_subscription)||'"'||' , "product_desc" : "'||compress(product_desc)||'"}]');
end;
else if first.cpn then do;
    flag = 'first';
    concat = ('subscriptions:[{'||'"mpc" : "'||compress(mpc)||'" , '||'"contract_start_date" : "'||compress(contract_start_date)||'" '||' , "contract_end_date" : "'||compress(contract_end_date)||'"'||' , "subscription_status_code" : "'||compress(subscription_status_code)||'"'||' , '||'"promo_code" : "'||compress(promo_code)||'" '||' , "print_or_digi_flag" : "'||compress(print_or_digi_flag)||'"'||' , "payment_method_selection" : "'||compress(payment_method_selection)||'"'||', "subscription_type_code" : "'||compress(subscription_type_code)||'"'||' , "report_trial_subscription" : "'||compress(report_trial_subscription)||'"'||' , "product_desc" : "'||compress(product_desc)||'"} , ');
end;
else if last.cpn then do;
    flag = 'last';
    concat = ('{"mpc" : "'||compress(mpc)||'" , '||'"contract_start_date" : "'||compress(contract_start_date)||'" '||' , "contract_end_date" : "'||compress(contract_end_date)||'"'||' , "subscription_status_code" : "'||compress(subscription_status_code)||'"'||' , '||'"promo_code" : "'||compress(promo_code)||'" '||' , "print_or_digi_flag" : "'||compress(print_or_digi_flag)||'"'||' , "payment_method_selection" : "'||compress(payment_method_selection)||'"'||', "subscription_type_code" : "'||compress(subscription_type_code)||'"'||' , "report_trial_subscription" : "'||compress(report_trial_subscription)||'"'||' , "product_desc" : "'||compress(product_desc)||'"  }]');
end;
else if not  first.cpn and not last.cpn then do;
    flag = 'none';
    concat = trim(('{"mpc" : "'||compress(mpc)||'" , '||'"contract_start_date" : "'||compress(contract_start_date)||'" '||' , "contract_end_date" : "'||compress(contract_end_date)||'"'||' , "subscription_status_code" : "'||compress(subscription_status_code)||'"'||' , '||'"promo_code" : "'||compress(promo_code)||'" '||' , "print_or_digi_flag" : "'||compress(print_or_digi_flag)||'"'||' , "payment_method_selection" : "'||compress(payment_method_selection)||'"'||', "subscription_type_code" : "'||compress(subscription_type_code)||'"'||' , "report_trial_subscription" : "'||compress(report_trial_subscription)||'"'||' , "product_desc" : "'||compress(product_desc)||'"} , '));
end;
if first.cpn then json_array = trim(concat);
   else json_array = trim(json_array)||trim(concat);
run;
```

If, for instance, there are 4 records for a cpn,
and the length of json_array reaches 955 on the third record - this is where the value is trimmed and that is the final result for json_array for that cpn.
Both json_array & concat are set to 10,000 positions.
Why is it trimmed?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Trimmed? Or does it just stop growing since nothing is ever put into CONCAT to get added it to?

Comment: Trimmed. The final value (the concatenated one) is in variable json_array

Comment: Where is the length of CONCAT and JSON_ARRAY set?  It is not in the code you posted.  Also do either have formats attached to them?  If you define JSON_ARRAY with length $10000 put attach the format $955. to it then normal attempts to look at the value will make it look truncated.

Comment: As I am developing in DI, I set the length & format to the metadata object. Anyway, I took your advise and it actually works now. Thanks a lot Tom!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the SAS Documentation on TRIM() (https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/67960/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1io938ofitwnzn18e1hzel3u9ut.htm)

In a DATA step, if the TRIM function returns a value to a variable that has not previously been assigned a length, then that variable is given the length of the argument.

If the size of `JSON_ARRAY` is not explicitly set, then it will be the length of `CONCAT`.  If you don't set the length of `CONCAT`, then it will be the length it is first assigned (in this case, 955).

So add a `FORMAT`, or `LENGTH` statement and set `JSON_ARRAY` (you should do `CONCAT` too) and you should be good to go.

Comment: That was new to me. Thank you @DomPazz !